# Python 2.7 - search for a particular URL on a webpage with ajax

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have to retrieve a URL that is nested in a webpage. I have tried the following code but it does not find the URL of the main link (to a PDF).

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.cmc.gv.ao/sites/main/pt/Paginas/genericFileList.aspx?mid=9&smid=69&FilterField1=TipoConteudo_x003A_Code&FilterValue1=ENTREG"

conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = conn.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all('a')

for tag in links:
    link = tag.get('href',None)
    if link is not None:
        print link
```

The URL I would like to find is the main link on the web page:

http://www.cmc.gv.ao/sites/main/pt/Lists/CMC%20%20PublicaesFicheiros/Attachments/89/Lista%20de%20Institui%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20Registadas%20(actualizado%2024.10.16).pdf

In the bs4 documents it says that the find_all() method looks through a tag's descendants (direct children, children of direct children and so on) and retrieves *all* descendants that match your filters.

How do I get the URL from the webpage?

Comment: Have you tried `soup.select('a')`?

Comment: this page use JavaScript to read data and add it on page. `urllib` and `BS4` doesn't run JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *pdf path* is retrieved using an ajax request, you need to do a bit of work to mimic the request:

```
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "http://www.cmc.gv.ao/sites/main/pt/Paginas/genericFileList.aspx?mid=9&smid=69&FilterField1=TipoConteudo_x003A_Code&FilterValue1=ENTREG"

conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = conn.read()

# we need to pass in the getbyid value which we parse later
attach = "http://www.cmc.gv.ao/sites/main/pt/_api/web/lists/getbyid('{}')/items(89)/AttachmentFiles"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# the getbyid is contained inside a script tag, this will pull what er need from it.
patt = re.compile('ctx.editFormUrl\s+=\s+"(.*?)"')

# find that script.
scr = soup.find("script",text=re.compile("ctx.editFormUrl"))

# line we are getting looks like ctx.editFormUrl = "http://www.cmc.gv.ao/sites/main/pt/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=6&ListId=%7BC0527FB1%2D00D9%2D4BCF%2D8FFC%2DDFCAA9E9E51D%7D";
# we need the ListId

ctx = patt.search(scr.text).group(1)

# pull ListId, and pass it to url
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(attach.format(ctx.rsplit("=")[-1])).read())

# ^^ returns xml, we need to find the pdf path from that, it starts with /sites/main/pt/List.
pdf_path = soup2.find(text=re.compile("^/sites/main/pt/List"))
```

Then you need to join to the base url:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
# join our parsed path to the base
full_url = urljoin("http://www.cmc.gv.ao", pdf_path)
print(full_url)
```

we also need to quote and encode:

```
from urllib import quote
from urlparse import urljoin

# handle non-ascii and encode
full_url = urljoin("http://www.cmc.gv.ao", quote(pdf_path.encode("utf-8")))
```

And finally to write:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
from urllib import quote

full_url = urljoin("http://www.cmc.gv.ao", quote(pdf_path.encode("utf-8")))
from os.path import basename
with open(basename(pdf_path.encode("utf-8")), "wb") as f:
    f.writelines(urllib2.urlopen(full_url))
```

Which will give you a pdf file called *Lista de Instituições Registadas (actualizado 24.10.16).pdf*

If you use requests, it does a lot of the work for you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urlparse import urljoin
from os.path import basename

url = "http://www.cmc.gv.ao/sites/main/pt/Paginas/genericFileList.aspx?mid=9&smid=69&FilterField1=TipoConteudo_x003A_Code&FilterValue1=ENTREG"

conn  = requests.get(url)
html = conn.content
attach = "http://www.cmc.gv.ao/sites/main/pt/_api/web/lists/getbyid('{}')/items(89)/AttachmentFiles"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all('a')
patt = re.compile('ctx.editFormUrl\s+=\s+"(.*?)"')
scr = soup.find("script",text=re.compile("ctx.editFormUrl"))

ctx = patt.search(scr.text).group(1)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(attach.format(ctx.rsplit("=")[-1])).content)

pdf_path = soup2.find(text=re.compile("/sites/main/pt/List"))

full_url = urljoin("http://www.cmc.gv.ao", pdf_path.encode("utf-8"))

with open(basename(pdf_path.encode("utf-8")), "wb") as f:
    f.writelines(requests.get(full_url))
```

Comment: This looks good but I am not getting a URL from pdf_url: http://www.cmc.gv.ao/sites/main/pt/_api/Web/Lists(guid'c0527fb1-00d9-4bcf-8ffc-dfcaa9e9e51d')/Items(89)/AttachmentFiles('Lista de Instituições Registadas (actualizado 24.10.16).pdf')

Comment: This is in the ... part of the above: (guid'c0527fb1-00d9-4bcf-8ffc-dfcaa9e9e51d')/Items(89)/AttachmentFiles

Comment: @Astrophe sorry, the actual path is under a different tag,  see the edit

Comment: there seems to be a disjoin between the base url and pdf_path. I just tried to strip() pdf_path but that didn't do it.

Comment: I get an error trying to import urljoin: ImportError: cannot import name urljoin

Comment: Thanks that held me back for longer than I would like to admit. I tried flattening the HTML tree and identifying the exact nesting to try to dig out the URL. This is really helpful.

Comment: @Astrophe,  should have been from urlparse import urljoin, it would certainly  not be exactly be the easiest url you will ever have to get!

Comment: Thanks for including comments and also for writing up the equivalent code using requests.